# How to convert Uri to string in a foolproof way

Tags: c#, .net, uri

The .NET `System.Uri` object is a good way to construct and analyze URIs, but its `ToString` method does some changes to the string that may make reading it better, but do not preserve the original string. Some sanitization is also missing if the URI is relative:

| Original string | `ToString` |
| --- | --- |
| `C:\a` | `file:///C:/a` |
| `urn:%%%` | `urn:%25%25%25` |
| `urn:%E2%98%BA` | `urn:☺` |
| `%%%` | `%%%` |
| `%E2%98%BA` | `☺` |

What is the best way to format the object for other URI-accepting services so that most of the syntax is preserved?

Answer (score 1):

For absolute URIs, `Uri.AbsoluteUri` is already the best property to use to get a properly-structured URI as close as possible to the original. This still means system paths have to be converted to `file:///`, but original percent-encoding is preserved and new is introduced in attempt to make it valid.

Relative URIs only expose the `OriginalString` property that always stores the original string as passed to the constructor. From there, it could be appended to an absolute URI and retrieved back:

```cs
public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static string ToSafeString(this Uri uri)
    {
        if(uri.IsAbsoluteUri) return uri.AbsoluteUri;
        const string prefix = "about:invalid?";
        return new Uri(prefix + uri.OriginalString, UriKind.Absolute).AbsoluteUri.Substring(prefix.Length);
    }
}
```

The prefix contains the query portion so that .NET doesn't attempt to treat it in any special way (like a URI path). This makes formatting URIs consistent between absolute and relative URIs.

Note that .NET does not validate the result in 100% accordance to the RFCs. For example, `[` and `]` characters are not escaped anywhere, and `#` can be present more than once.

This approach is however also not perfect for IRIs, as `☺` gets escaped in all cases. You can either choose to use `AbsoluteUri` which preserves escaping but converts IRI to URI, or `ToString()` which does the opposite (but the result is still consistently sanitized with this approach). Unfortunately, to preserve everything, one has to rely on `OriginalString` and sanitize that in some way, essentially making their own version of the URI parser.